# SQL Server mirroring connection doesnt work

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

I have 2 servers `srv-erp1` and `srv-erp3`. I made them mirror on each other. All setup is done by lots of tutorials and examples.

But when I call

```
ALTER DATABASE MIRROR_TEST SET PARTNER = 'TCP://srv-erp3:5022'
```

It`s response is:

> The server network address "TCP://srv-erp3:5022" can not be reached or
>   does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for
>   the local and remote endpoints are operational.

I go to cmd on `srv-erp3` and use `netstat -an...` this port is listening.
I go to cmd on `srv-erp1` and use `telnet srv-erp3 5022...`and its ok to connect.

All firewalls are turned off. The only difference in config of srvrs is that `srv-erp1` is on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64, and `srv-erp3` is on Windows 2008 R2 x64

What can be the reason of this problem?

Regards, Dmitry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have such problem, the solution was [using certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191140.aspx). My problem appeared because my servers were not in one domain.

Comment: Thats the problem, that my servers are in one domain and I do use certificates

Comment: I tried almost every thing...Configured via manager and not, used different ports etc. They just cant see each other via mirroring service(

Comment: stupid idea: did you checked SQL Server Configuration Manager to check the server and clinets protocols you use? Few days ago I found that on one of my sever named pipes protocol is enabled, but TCP/IP is disabled (or vice versa)...

Comment: I used your link to make new try...
now when I`m setting a partner, it throws another error:

MSG 1416: Database "MIRROR_TEST" is not configured for database mirroring.

Comment: I hope now it will be easy. First, backup the database on primary server, thern copy the backup to the mirror server and then restore the database with NORECOVERY option. Then backup the LOG (I hope your database is in FULL recovery mode) on the primary database, copy to mirror and restore this log with NORECOVERY option. And then try to start mirroring as soon as you can.